# Deleting "has" files

Tags: perforce

Title pretty much sums it up: Is there a way to delete "has" state on a Perforce server after a sync has been done without using `-p`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `p4 flush FILE@0` (a synonym for `p4 sync -k FILE@0`).  This will tell the server that you've synced `FILE` to change 0 (meaning that you no longer "have" it) without affecting your local copy.